ExtJs - adding a template on a lower layer than the table
I have created an order book in Extjs but because I used this solution I don't really know how to upload another thing here.
I would like to add in the background quarters with a different color and border. I would also like to have a different color space and border in the middle part. I depict it in the pictures below.
Unfortunately, by choosing to build on the table and cells, I don't have much possibility to manipulate it in such a way through CSS. I was thinking of adding such a template here in the background, but I can't manipulate the height and width when adding new tiles.
current view of the component
background that I want to add here 
I add the code, of course, and ask for questions if there is not enough information.


items: [
    {
      xtype: 'grid',
      cls: 'order-book',


      viewConfig: {
        getRowClass: function (record) {
          if (record.get('sell').length > 0) {
            return 'sell-row'
          } else if (record.get('buy').length > 0) {
            return 'buy-row'
          }
          return ''
        },
      },

      columns: [
        ...Array.from({ length: 4 }, (_, index) => ({
          renderer: function (value, gridcell, record) {
            value = record.get('sell')[3 - index]
            if (value) {
              gridcell.tdCls = 'sell'
              return (
                ('Example' || '') +
                '<br />' +
                value.quantity
              )
            } else {
              gridcell.tdCls = ''
            }
          },
        })),
        {
          dataIndex: 'price',
          renderer: function (value, gridcell, record) {
            let quantity = 0
            record
              .get('sell')
              .forEach((num) => (quantity += Number(num.quantity)))
            record
              .get('buy')
              .forEach((num) => (quantity += Number(num.quantity)))
            gridcell.tdCls = 'amount'
            return `${Common.Formatter.moneyFormat({ price: value })}<br />${quantity}`
          },
        },
        ...Array.from({ length: 4 }, (_, index) => ({
          renderer: function (value, gridcell, record) {
            value = record.get('buy')[index]
            if (value) {
              gridcell.tdCls = 'buy'
              return (
                ('Example'|| '') +
                '<br />' +
                value.quantity
              )
            } else {
              gridcell.tdCls = ''
            }
          },
        })),
      ],
    },
  ],




Please add mark answers as correct, if the answers works. Otherwise there will be open questions, although answers do work.

In your example you are using
...Array.from

Please make sure that this still works after you use sencha app build production. There is a high chance it won't work that way.
ExtJS does not support all of the latest JS.
You can style the items based on classes.
First you add a style buy-base in addition to all buy columns (sale-base
for the sale columns).
    customRenderer:  function (value, gridcell, record) {
        const type = gridcell.column.dataAction[0],
              row = gridcell.column.dataAction[1];
        let baseCls = type + '-base ';

        if (type == 'sell' && row === 0 || type == 'buy' && row === 3) {
            baseCls += 'border-right '
        }
        if (type == 'sell' && row === 3 || type == 'buy' && row === 0) {
            baseCls += 'border-left '
        }

        value = record.get(type)[row];

        if (value) {
            gridcell.tdCls = baseCls + type;
        } else {
            gridcell.tdCls = baseCls + '';
        }

        return value;
    }

Then add something like the following styling. You have to use the classes buy-baseand sale-base to make this happen.
Here is a good starting point.
The fiddle shows the result of this approach, which still needs the buy-base style
.x-grid-item .x-grid-cell {
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: white;
}

.border-left {
    border-left-width: 1px;
}

.border-right {
    border-right-width: 1px;
}

.x-grid-item:first-child .x-grid-cell.sell-base,
.x-grid-item:first-child .x-grid-cell.buy-base {
    border-top-width: 1px;
}

.x-grid-item:last-child .x-grid-cell.sell-base,
.x-grid-item:last-child .x-grid-cell.buy-base {
    border-bottom-width: 1px;
}


Unfortunately, it doesn't work exactly as I would like. borders are displayed but they are not where they should be and they look like a dashed line because other things are covering them
